# How to moving a specific sprite

Tags: ios, swift

In my game i have four sprites , users should touch each one individually , this is my code

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

     for touch: AnyObject in touches{

     let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

     let newposition2 = CGPointMake(location.x, 15)

            self.brick2.position=newposition2

}
```

It works well , but After i added first sprite , i can control it from any place in the screen , i want when i touch first sprite it self should move , otherwise , it's still at its place

I hope my words are clear enough..

Comment: Take a look at [how to drag and drop sprites](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way in your method:

```
for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == yourSprite {
            //This will call when you touch sprite
            //change your sprite location

        }
}
```

hope this will help.